# Best way of including a View without extra modules as Panels, CTools, Context, etc

Tags: views

I have a View which shows a list of nodes of a certain type.
If I don't want to use additional modules as Panels, CTools, Context, etc... which is the faster and better way of including it in a landing page? I have made a new kind of content for the landing page, with its own URL in PathAuto, and in the template.tpl I embed the Views with views_embed_view. Is it a good idea? Is it the simplest way of doing it? I have managed to get all working but the method seems very cumbersome and strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*views_embed_view* is a common method of doing it with highly degree of flexibility. Make sure that the type of the view's display (of the embedded view) is **Embed**. This display type can be made accessible in views UI by enabling it inside view's advanced settings.

Answer (score 1):

probably the most flexible method is to create the View as a block, and then put the block in the appropriate place restricted by content type, url, user, or any other restrictions you wish to impose.